# Application crashes when trying to background remove on a TestFlight?

Tags: swift, xcode, mobile

I’m trying to remove the background from the UIImageView. I use DeepLabV3 Library, it's working on my device or simulator there is no problem here.

When I send to a new build on TestFlight, its only crashes on the TestFlight version.

I don’t understand the problem, I tried to some changes and research on the other source but I can’t get any solution.

Deployment Info: IOS15

here is a screenshot of the error:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCIp5.jpg)

here is the code:

```
    // modified from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/applying_a_chroma_key_effect
private func chromaKeyFilter() -> CIFilter? {
    let size = 64
    var cubeRGB = [Float]()
    
    for z in 0 ..< size {
        let blue = CGFloat(z) / CGFloat(size-1)
        for y in 0 ..< size {
            let green = CGFloat(y) / CGFloat(size-1)
            for x in 0 ..< size {
                let red = CGFloat(x) / CGFloat(size-1)
                let brightness = getBrightness(red: red, green: green, blue: blue)
                let alpha: CGFloat = brightness == 1 ? 0 : 1
                cubeRGB.append(Float(red * alpha))
                cubeRGB.append(Float(green * alpha))
                cubeRGB.append(Float(blue * alpha))
                cubeRGB.append(Float(alpha))
            }
        }
    }
    
    let data = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &cubeRGB, count: cubeRGB.count))
    
    let colorCubeFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorCube", parameters: ["inputCubeDimension": size, "inputCubeData": data])
    return colorCubeFilter
}
```

Thanks for your help :)